# Show fragment after calling dragndrop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

In my app fragment(first fragment) where user can press on item and app will show fragment with list(second fragment), where user can drop caught item.
Code:

```
 public void startDragNDrop(){
      showFragmentWithList();
      JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
      object.put(Constants.PARAM_ID, getId());
      ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", object.toString());
      View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(mMainLayout);
      mMainLayout.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, mMainLayout, 0);
 }
```

And when second fragment catches `ACTION_DROP` it will close himself. And it works well, but if user remove finger faster than method finish their work, dragndrop won't start and second fragment won't receive dragndrop event, as result new fragment won't disappear.

I tried to fix it via setting dragndrop listener at first fragment and when it will catch `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` it will call `showFragmentWithList()` and fragment  will show. But I faced of new problem, `View.OnDragListener` doesn't work for any views inside of second fragment. Can somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should start a drag-n-drop action prior to showing the second fragment, not the other way around. This is a natural order of events. This way you won't end up in a situation when the second fragment has already been shown but the actual drag-n-drop hasn't started yet.

It's hard to tell from the question where is the root of the problem but I would suggest trying to use a UI handler instead of calling methods directly. This way events will go to the UI message queue and thus, will be dispatched after the system events such as `onStart()`, `onResume()` and so forth. This might fix the problem of not receiving events in the second fragment.

Also please make sure your first fragment doesn't "steal" those drag events from the second fragment. Maybe it's your first fragment who receives `ACTION_DROP` and that's why the second one doesn't. Hope that helps.